# TypeScript method argument to force optional type

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write a function declaration like:

```
function foo(arg?: string)
```

So that the only accepted type would be of `string?`. Meaning that following would give error

```
function bar(arg: string) {
    foo(arg);   <--- Would give error because known type of arg is `string` instead of `string?`
}
```

Clearly the `arg?: string` is not the way to do it, but is there some way to achieve this?

Edit: Adding a reason why I need this.

Code base currently have asserts in place like:

```
// Person age is optional field on data model
cont age = assertExists(person.age)
```

Which are used to fail fast in case some property needed is not set (data coming from upstream). After some refactoring some of the properties from upstream are no longer optional so some asserts are no longer needed.

Compiler does not tell me which ones are now obsolete as the signature is:

```
function assertExists<T>(item: T | undefined | null, message?: string): T
```

So I would like to change the signature of the `assertExists` so that compiler would give error if e.g. passing type of `string` to it.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a reason, why do you need this? Type `string` is assignable to `string?`

Comment: personally, I don't think it's possible cuz `string` would always be accepted by a `string | undefined` type.

Comment: This is impossible as stated.  What is the underlying use case for this? That is, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve?  Maybe there's a way to achieve *that*.  Without this information the only way to answer this is with "no" and possibly a reason why.  Is that what you want to see?

Comment: Updated description with the reason why I would need this

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKRZpm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Nice! It works! What a sorcery.

Answer (score 0):

If an argument is forced to be optional, it means that it won't never passed... so you should delete it.

*Edit:* reviewing my answer after that @Rapie had added the reason for this question.

In order to modify the `assertExists`' signature in the way that when we pass an argument that isn't optional and then the compiler raise an error, we have to force the parameter item's type to be optional. Otherwise if the argument is optional, the compiler won't raise an error.

For being sure that the passed argument is optional, the intersection between its type (if it is optional, it will be like `T | undefined`) and `undefined` must be valid.

To check this thing we use this casting instruction when we are calling the function:

```js
// it will raise TS 2352 if item's type isn't T | undefined
assertExists<T>(item as (T | undefined) & undefined);
```

Therefore the most appropriate `assertExists`' signature will be:

```js
function assertExists<T>(item: (T & undefined) | undefined, message?: string): T;
```

*Note:* `(T & undefined) | undefined` is equivalent to `(T | undefined) & undefined` (or `(T | undefined) & (undefined | undefined)`) because of distributive property of the union with respect to the intersection.

Comment: Not the value but the type of the argument.

Comment: @Raipe there is no sense to add an argument if it will be always optional... simply it means you don't need that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you check the answer by jcalz above you see this is possible and there is a use case for it.

Comment: @Raipe yeah, I have figured out what you have meant. I'll update my answer later because I think I have found a solution.